# Android project build error: skipping (null) file, android aapt error

Tags: android, aapt

I'm new to Android development. I download an opensource android project:
[open source china android client](http://git.oschina.net/oschina/android-app)
after import the project into eclipse workspace, there are some error.
The main error is cause by some PNG file. I googled `skipping null file android` but found no help information.
How to fix these error? Thanks

FYI: You can download the source code from http://git.oschina.net/oschina/android-app by click '[下载zip](http://git.oschina.net/oschina/android-app/repository/archive?ref=master)'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading underscore in file name will fix it